# config for PATH variable on mac

Tags: unix

I have the following `env` file which is run whenever the shell starts:

```
PATH=/Users/paulcowan/bin:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
PATH=$PATH:"$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

But when I run `echo $PATH`

I get:

`/Users/paulcowan/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin:/usr/local/rbenv/shims:PATH:/Users/paulcowan/.local/bin:/Users/paulcowan/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/local/rbenv/shims:PATH:/Users/paulcowan/.local/bin:/Users/paulcowan/bin:/Users/paulcowan/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/rbenv/bin:PATH:/Users/paulcowan/.local/bin:/Users/paulcowan/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/local/rbenv/shims:PATH:/Users/paulcowan/.local/bin:/Users/paulcowan/bin:/Users/paulcowan/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`

With the same values repeating.

How can I properly configure my path?

Comment: While you added the "$" in the 3rd line presented above, the existence of multiple occurrences of the word "PATH" in your output tells me that you probably did not have that missing "$" in your env file.

Answer (score 2):

You repeated the $PATH at the beginning and end of several of the lines:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:"$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
```

Why not just set it like this?

```
export PATH=/Users/paulcowan/bin:~/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood what your script tries to do, the correct code could be:

```
PATH=/Users/paulcowan/bin:$PATH
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
PATH=/bin:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:$RBENV_ROOT/bin
export PATH
```